# Powershell script outputs numbers with comma decimal on one machine and period decimals on another

Tags: sql-server, powershell, format, export-to-csv

I have a PowerShell script that exports data from a database into a CSV file. The consumers of the csv expect numbers in the file to have a period as a decimal point. The PowerShell script is being executed in WhereScape Red where the metadata format for each numeric field in the database is defined as #.##0. When the script is run in the dev environment I get the correct output. This is shown below:

[image]

When the same script, metadata, and application are deployed to the Test environment I get the output with numbers having a comma as a decimal point. I assume there is a local cultural setting that is causing this. Is there a way to ensure I have a period as a decimal point regardless of local cultural settings?

The Powershell script I wrote is shown below

```
#############################################################
#
# - Name: Create_Ldr_Files_GDM
#
# - Purpose: This script exports GDM tables to csv for WKSaaS
#
#############################################################
# - Change history:
# - Date      Intials    Notes
# - --------  -------    ------------------------------------
# - 20231204  EOS      Initial Version
# - 
#############################################################

#############################################################
#                     Functions                             *
#############################################################
$RepoDsn        = ${env:WSL_META_DSN}
$p_gdm_ldr_param_path   = "Path_GDM_AC"
$p_gdm_ctl_param_path   = "Path_GDM_ctl_AC"


function get_param_value ($p_gdm_ldr_param_path, $RepoDsn){
    $sql = "select [dbo].[WsParameterReadF] ('$p_gdm_ldr_param_path') as src_path"
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=$RepoDsn;Uid=$RepoUser;Pwd=$RepoPass"
    $conn.open()
    $cmd = [system.data.odbc.odbcCommand]::new($sql,$conn) 
    $adapter = [system.data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter]::new($cmd) 
    $dr = [system.data.dataSet]::new() 
    [Void]$adapter.Fill($dr) 
    $conn.close()
    $path_file = $dr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["src_path"]
    
    return $path_file
}

$server =  ${env:WSL_META_SERVER} 
$database = "PUB_FINANCE"
$tablequery = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [PUB_FINANCE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='gdm' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' AND (TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'mapping%' and TABLE_NAME != 'vw_gdm_ACBS_LodAmount')"
$fileDirectory =  get_param_value $p_gdm_ldr_param_path $RepoDsn 
$ctlFileDirectory = get_param_value $p_gdm_ctl_param_path $RepoDsn

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
 
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection
 
#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

# delete contents of output directory

Get-Childitem -Path $fileDirectory | Remove-Item

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [PUB_FINANCE].[gdm].[$($Row[0])]"

    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "$($fileDirectory)\$($Row[0]).ldr"

    #have to remove the vw_ from the file name as data is coming from staging out views but filename needs to be the same as the table
    #eg vw_COUNTERPARTY.ctl -> COUNTERPARTY.ctl
    $parseExtractFile =  $extractFile.replace('vw_','')
     
    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection
 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()
         
   
        if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
               Out-File $parseExtractFile
         }
 
       else {
        $DataSet.Tables[0]  |  ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1| Set- Content $parseExtractFile
        }
        
}

# Copy ctl files to output directory

Copy-Item -Path $ctlFileDirectory\*.ctl  -Destination $fileDirectory  

$RESULT_CODE = 1
$RESULT_MSG = "ctl and loaded files have been created"
Write-Output $RESULT_CODE
Write-Output $RESULT_MSG
```

Comment: Can you try calling [set-culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in your script before writing to csv? Or similarly if any on the .net objects you are using along the way accept `CultureInfo` you could try setting those accordingly

Comment: I'd also step through the whole process and try to isolate where the conversion is taking place. I.e, make sure the db isn't storing them as strings or something weird, then check the output of the `SqlCommand`, then the `DataSet` etc.

Comment: You might want to use the InvariantCulture to ensure the same result regardless of in which culture the code is executed. `[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::InvariantInfo` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SHOULD change the culture only for the scope of the script.
Thanks to  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/using-culture-culture-culture-script-scriptblock/

```
# save current CUlture info
$OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

# start trap to make sure it reverts should anything break
trap {
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
}

# set the new Culture.
# It-IT (Italian) uses commas for decimal separator, but feel free to use anything you want
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [cultureInfo]::GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag('it-it')


# start of your code
if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
    Out-File $parseExtractFile
}
else {
    $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set- Content $parseExtractFile
}


# reverts culture to the original
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
```

Answer (score -2):

Check for language settings of the test environment. In languages like German period is equivalent to comma.

Comment: The language setting is Dutch Netherlands. In any case I cannot alter the language settings for the servers.